# how to do integration test for java akka system project to test its performance

Tags: java, akka, integration-testing

I have 5 actors in java code .
An actor initiates other actor and makes a complete chain till end.
Currently i have written a main funtion to initiate an actor like :

```
startActor.tell(message,ActroRef.noSender);
```

i want to do performance test of my project. So i want to do Integration Test.

currently i was trying to test it with [gatling](http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.2/). but it tests only http request and i have not any http url to test.

Please suggest me any ependency or tools to achieve my goal.

Comment: This is a very weird test. I don't see the reason for doing it at all. If I understood you correctly, you have a strange setup of 5 actors sequentially messaging the next, and you want to measure what? Latency, throughput? Of what? Akka? Anyway, if you need a generic performance measure tool, then use JMeter. But for this case I think the simplest unit test would work.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.... i enlightened :)